# Understanding netstat output

Tags: port, netstat

Below is an output from a netstat command:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5040           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7680           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8089           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8191           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:21112          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49666          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49669          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49670          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49701          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49723          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:56220          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:61116          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    13.2.2.54:139        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5939         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8065         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:10134        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:12668        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62522        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

I'm trying to figure out which port is open on my PC. My understanding is, the line with `13.2.2.54:139` tells me that my PC has port 139 open (correct me if I'm wrong). Then again, I see `127.0.0.1` with multiple ports and it looks as if those ports are also open on my PC. Or does the output above mean that all the ports above are open?

I've read some information online but still getting answers that don't answer my question.

All I'm looking for is what port(s) are open on my PC. Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the ports above are listening for connections, hence why it says 'Listening'.

However, most are listening to connections on 'Any' IP your machine may have, so that can be the local loopback address (127.0.0.1) but also any IP given on any interface on your machine - In this case you can see that one process is listening on port 139 (NetBios), on what appears to be your internet connection.

```
TCP    13.2.2.54:139        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

While some are only listening on the loopback addresses:

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:8065       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

which means only a connection from your machine, to these ports, would succeed.

Comment: Just FYI: Exposing the NetBios port 139 to the internet is a really bad idea because it is a serious security risk.

Comment: @zx485 Yup. I'm aware. However, I just made up that IP:)